# Close menu by clicking outside it

Tags: javascript, html, menu, onclick

I have created a mobile menu that opens on clicking the hamburger button. At present I can only close the menu by clicking the hamburger button. What do I need to add to be able to close the menu by clicking elsewhere on the page?

Code below.

Apologies for the basic question! Thanks in advance for any help.

Jordan

```js
   function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
      if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
    <a href="#home" class="nt"><strong>NELSON TRAILS</strong></a>
    <div id="myLinks">
    <a class="sub">SHORT WALKS</a>
    <a class="sub">DAY TRIPS</a>
    <a class="sub">MULTI-DAY</a>
    <a class="sub">MAP EXPLORER</a> 
    <a class="sub">TRAIL SEARCH AND FILTER</a>
    <a class="sub">TRAIL ALERTS</a>
    <a class="sub">ABOUT</a>
 </div>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, one if using a generic onclick event in a superior element.
Here is an example:

```js
function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
      if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
    
window.onclick = myFunction;
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
    <a href="#home" class="nt"><strong>NELSON TRAILS</strong></a>
    <div id="myLinks">
    <a class="sub">SHORT WALKS</a>
    <a class="sub">DAY TRIPS</a>
    <a class="sub">MULTI-DAY</a>
    <a class="sub">MAP EXPLORER</a> 
    <a class="sub">TRAIL SEARCH AND FILTER</a>
    <a class="sub">TRAIL ALERTS</a>
    <a class="sub">ABOUT</a>
 </div>
 <a class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars">Menu</i></a>
</div>
```

Of course `window` isn't a good element to use because it polutes js namespace. Put this in an element which is above your menu and that covers the whole page.
You can use a root div or something like that.

Comment: You could use <body> instead of window

Comment: @Chipster tried, but at least in the snippet it didn't work. If you know how to get it to work, please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks @NelsonTeixeira, the window method works, though the issue is that clicking in the window will open the menu, rather than only when you click the menu button. Sorry, I should have included the CSS as it's a little difficult to see in the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous answer said, there are many ways to solve this. An alternative way is utilize the [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) and [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur) events. As the previous comment said, you might want to avoid polluting the global name space.

Here is an implementation utilizing focus and blur events.

```js
function onClick(e) {
  if (myLinks.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    myLinks.classList.remove('hidden');
    navMenu.focus();
  } else {
    myLinks.classList.add('hidden');
    navMenu.blur()
  }
}

function onBlur() {
  myLinks.classList.add('hidden');
}

var myLinks = document.getElementById("myLinks");
var navMenu = document.querySelector('.topnav')
var myBtn = document.getElementById('home');
myBtn.addEventListener('click', onClick);
navMenu.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
```

```css
.topnav {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}

.sub {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" tabindex="0">
  <a id="home" class="nt"><strong>NELSON TRAILS</strong></a>
  <div id="myLinks" class="hidden">
    <a class="sub">SHORT WALKS</a>
    <a class="sub">DAY TRIPS</a>
    <a class="sub">MULTI-DAY</a>
    <a class="sub">MAP EXPLORER</a>
    <a class="sub">TRAIL SEARCH AND FILTER</a>
    <a class="sub">TRAIL ALERTS</a>
    <a class="sub">ABOUT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This method probably not the best (one with blur/focus is better imo) but there a lot of different ways to do it so here goes another one.

```js
function openModal(){
 var x = document.getElementById('myLinks');
 if(x.style.display != 'block'){
  x.style.display = 'block';
  window.addEventListener('click', closeMenu, {capture: true});
 }
}

function closeMenu(event){
 var el = document.getElementById('myLinks');
 if(el.style.display == 'block' && event.target != el){
  window.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu, {capture: true});
  el.style.display = 'none';
 }
}
```

```css
div#myLinks{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
    <a href="#home" class="nt"><strong>NELSON TRAILS</strong></a>
    <div id="myLinks">
    <a class="sub">SHORT WALKS</a>
    <a class="sub">DAY TRIPS</a>
    <a class="sub">MULTI-DAY</a>
    <a class="sub">MAP EXPLORER</a> 
    <a class="sub">TRAIL SEARCH AND FILTER</a>
    <a class="sub">TRAIL ALERTS</a>
    <a class="sub">ABOUT</a>
 </div>
 <p class="icon" onclick="openModal()">Menu</p>
</div>
```

We need `capture` option for event listener so it wont fire after initial click. This method is much less poluting the `window` because our listener exists only when menu is open.

Also you shouldn't use `javascript:void(0)` for preventing redirecting.
What you should do is something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 document.querySelectorAll('a.prevent-default').forEach(function(el, i){
  el.addEventListener('click', preventDefault);
 });
});

function preventDefault(event){
 event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a href="google.com" class="my-class prevent-default">Can't go through me!</a>
```

This will find of all `a` elements with class `prevent-default` and prevent redirecting. Use of `href="javascript:void(0);"` is something to leave in the past.